# Convert an Oracle 10g RAC database to single instance

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-rac

In an attempt to reduce the complexity of a solution, I've been asked to convert a two node Oracle 10g RAC production database to single instance. The database is running on RHEL5 with ASM on SAN.

I imagine at least the following steps will be required:

- Remove the instances from cluster ready services
- Restrict the second node's access to shared storage
- Remove redo logs for second instance
- Drop undo tablespace for second instance
- Remove references to second instance from the pfile/spfile
- Relink the Oracle binaries, refer to post from Gaius

Any other considerations?
Might it be better to create a single node physical standby?

Does anyone know of a related whitepaper or metalink note?

Comment: what is the "original question"? you should link to the original question.

Comment: The original question? I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does [this link](http://2jliu.itpub.net/post/21805/497324) helps?

For ASM, edit the ASM pfile and remove these lines

```
cluster_database=TRUE
+ASM.instance_number=<somthing>
```

You may also found metalink 239998.1 helpful if rootdelete.sh fails.

Comment: Yes it does, thank you. Although, I'm wondering if there might be some special considerations with regards to ASM.

Comment: updated for asm

Answer (score 1):

You will also need to relink the Oracle binaries:

```
$ cd $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/lib
$ make -f ins_rdbms.mk rac_off
$ make -f ins_rdbms.mk ioracle
```

Of course, if you create a single-node standby it will already be "un-RAC'd" but you will still need to "clean up" the second redo thread etc. Just had a quick look on Metalink and their search engine finds lots of results converting from single instance to RAC but I don't think Oracle wants you to do it the other way 'round...

Comment: Good point, thanks. I've updated the original post.